# Wheel scrolling does not work anymore

Tags: mouse

I did an `apt-get update` and `upgrade` today and now the middle wheel on my mouse doesn't scroll in any program. I've tried finding documentation to get it to work again but to no avail. I even tried using gpointing-device-settings and that did not do the trick. I used xev to determine if the wheel is even being registered as a button and it's button 2. I was able to scroll internet browsers and in other programs, but now I get nothing.

I can open links by clicking the wheel button and I can paste, but no scroll function. I am using a Logitech G620 and up until today the mouse has worked fine.

How to solve this?

Comment: Is there anything suspicious in your System Settings in the Mouse settings? Besides, gpointing-device-settings doesn't work with Gtk3 and seems to be dead (I've emailed their dev mailinglist, and the only answer I received was from a guy who quit the team some years ago and had no idea he still was on that list)

Comment: the_Seppi, I haven't seen anything suspcious in my System Settings.  I also checked the Unity Tweak Tool...nothing there.  Thanks for the reply though.  I completely unistalled the gpointing-device-settings program tool

Answer (score 5):

I had to unplug the Unifying Receiver and plug it back in :)

Comment: Was the rest of the mouse working including left and right click before replugging?

Comment: Yes it did work

Comment: lol. Such a simple solution but worked perfectly.

Comment: 2 years later and it still helped me.

Answer (score 2):

open a terminal window and type xev.  an event tester window will pop open and you can see if all of your mouse functions are working.

it will show clicks, scrolls, movements, etc.

after testing my mouse, all of a sudden my scrolling started working again...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar circumstance where my HP wireless mouse's wheel stopped working after an update.

Disconnecting the receiver and reconnecting it worked for me.